# Flutter - Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I launched my app, I got this error message. I did not make any changes since last run, when everything was fine.
Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thank you.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.28.0].
> Required by:
> project :app > project :cloud_firestore > com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2 > io.grpc:grpc-android:1.28.0
> project :app > project :cloud_firestore > com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2 > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.28.0
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I've got same error =( Yesterday build was ok

Comment: Same issue here too. Build was working fine in the morning, but a few hours later I get this "502 Bad Gateway" error. Did you solve it?

Comment: You can adopt this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360614/12052309


You have to strictly set version for io.grpc:grpc-core

Answer (score 4):

The solution I founded was upgrade all my packages.

`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

After treat all the issues and problems.

Upgrade the kotlin version too.

from
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'`
to
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'`

Or the latest Kotlin version.

Try to run your project again.

Comment: **The solution above worked for me**. My error follows `Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:+` and ends with the same "exoplayer" error. There are at least [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166663/could-not-get-play-services-location-maven-metadata-xml-received-status-code) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70167923/could-not-build-flutter-android-build-received-status-code-502-from-server-ba) dupes. I ran `flutter clean` then `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`, and had to fix other broken deps afterwards, but I'm out of this quagmire. THANK YOU

Comment: Thanks Leonardo. Your answer helped a lot. I had to also upgrade gradle according to this advice https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1406

Answer (score 1):

Basic problem that version of **io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.28.0]** is not specified strictly and gradle have to find possible versions but google.bintray.com is down - no version listing available

1. Find what version is - this **[1.28.0]** mean it has versions range
   [Gradle Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)
2. The [ and ] symbols indicate an inclusive bound with only one version - so consider take exactly 1.28.0
3. Constrain your transitive dependency with maximum possible version 1.28.0

Edit your project **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    implementation('io.grpc:grpc-core') {
        version {
            strictly '1.28.0'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these three steps**

```
1. flutter pub cache repair.

2. flutter Clean.
```

**Finally and the most important**

**3. Modify the build.gradle file as below**
change ***jcenter()*** to ***mavenCentral()*** everywhare

**Before**

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
 }
```

**After**

```
 repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
 }
```

Good luck.